# AS3 ScrollPane MovieClips Removing Others

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a ScrollPane, and I am trying to add Movieclips to it. Well the movieclip does add, however when it adds, it removes the others previously added so it only shows one at a time.

My Code:

```
btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doadd);
var X = 0;
function doadd(Event):void {
    var S:MovieClip=new MovieClip()  
    var mp:oItem = new oItem();
    mpane.source=S;
    mp.y = X*25;
    mp.txtIn.text = X;
    MovieClip(mpane.content).addChild(mp);
    X++;
    mpane.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ScrollPane can only have one source - this is by design.

A good way to do what you want, would be to create a container Sprite and use that as the source, then add everything as a child to the container.

```
btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doadd);
var X = 0;

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();  //this will hold all your items and be the source of the scrollPane
mpane.source = container;  //set the source outside of your recuring doadd function

function doadd(Event):void { 
    var mp:oItem = new oItem();
    mp.y = X*25;
    mp.txtIn.text = X;
    container.addChild(mp); //add to the container
    X++;
    mpane.update(); //you still need update everytime the contents of the scrollpane can potentially change size
}
```